# Does an Svn Dump Grab Everything?

Tags: svn, unfuddle, svndump

I am using the free version of http://unfuddle.com/ for all my svn needs. They allow backing up but I can't find how to import my repositories in.

I see they allow you do use import by using a svn dump file.

> Can I import a dump file of my Subversion repository?
>
> You may do the following to load a dump file into a new Subversion
>   repository in your Unfuddle account:
>
> ```
> Create the repository in your Unfuddle account. This will ensure that you have an empty repository in which to load your dump file.
> ```
>
> Then make note of the repository's URL as you will need this in the
>   steps below.
>       Create a Subversion repository locally using "svnadmin create localrepo"
>       Load your dump file into this repository using "svnadmin load /path/to/localrepo < /path/to/dump"
>       Sync your local repository to your Unfuddle repository. To do this run the following two commands:
>
> ```
> svnsync init --username YOURUSERNAME http://SUBDOMAIN.unfuddle.com/svn/SUBDOMAIN_REPOABBREVIATION
> ```
>
> file:///path/to/localrepo
>       svnsync sync --username YOURUSERNAME http://SUBDOMAIN.unfuddle.com/svn/SUBDOMAIN_REPOABBREVIATION
>
> Note: you will need to use the actual username, subdomain, and
>   repository abbreviation in the above commands.
>
> If you experience difficulty with this, please email us at support and
>   we will be happy to assist you further.

What I am not sure is will this have all my commits, all my tags and all my branches (so an exact copy of what I am seeing right now in my repository).

Also with the backups what I get they come in this format.

```
my.project.20120.tar.gz
```

what extracts to

```
my.project.20120.tar
```

what extracts to a folder with alot of these files `projectNae.svn.dmp (file type is noted as Crash Dump File)`.

As these my dump files that I can use with their instructions I posted above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Svnsync **will tranfer** all data from (local) repo to (Unfuddle) repo.

But svnsync in no way related to svn dumps and your strange dmp-files (which *can be* daily (?) incremental (?) dumps of some repo)

Comment: Sorry I am not following. What is Svnsync and what is wrong with the files they gave me?

Comment: @chobo2 - Svnsync is tool **mentioned in quoted by you instruction** "how to import repo into Unfuddle". Files may be good - if you don't see at their content - do it. Dump from svnadmin dump are *readable text files*, my assumptions, what you files are filesystem-backups are **only assumptions**

Comment: Ah I completely skipped over that command. Well can I just do a regular svn dump and get every(tags,revsions,branches) and then use the svnsync tool to recreate the repo? Or something along those lines. I want to move some repos to a different account but I still don't know how and their support never gets back to me.

Comment: @chobo2 "can I just do a regular svn dump and get every(tags,revsions,branches) and then use the svnsync tool to recreate the repo?" - No, bo,no!!! **Or** `svnadmin dump` **or** `svnsync` for repo-transfer, not both

Comment: So what do you recommend I do so I can get what I want and transfer it to a new account?